# Do magnetic fields cause rotational inertia proportional to their magnetic moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, moment-of-inertia, magnetic-moment

If I have a stick that has a spinning disc on the end of it, and I try to rotate the stick, I will feel more inertia the faster the disc is spinning because I have to transform its rotational energy into a different axis. It seems intuitive to me that this would apply to electromagnetic fields as well, since you have to move all the energy in the field to another axis.

So if you had an MRI machine on an airplane and the plane tried to rotate, would it rotate more slowly when the machine was powered vs unpowered? If so, does this depend on whether the axis of the field is aligned with the axis of rotation? If they were aligned so that the dipoles are parallel to the body of the plane, could it roll without extra inertia?

I may be describing the Einstein-de Haas effect or gyromagnetism, but I am confused whether they are describing the same thing as me in different words or just a related concept.